# Hide div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="result">Fade me in and hide div hideme</div>
<div id="hideme">
    <form method="POST">
        YES <input type="radio" name="name" value="yes" />
        NO <input type="radio" name="name" value="no" checked />
        <p />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="HIDE NOW!" />
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#result').hide();
        $('#submit').click(function() {
            $('#hideme').hide();
            $('#result').fadeIn(5000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3252H/)

Why is the second hide not working after clicking and fadeOut the div

Comment: Because you submit the form! If you need the form to stay, you need to ajax and preventDefault submission. ALso never call anything in a form name="submit". Also please use a jQuery from this century

Comment: Strictly speaking, isn't *all* jQuery from 'this century'? It was only released in '06, after all...

Comment: I was exaggerating... this century "internet time"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behaviour of the `submit` button. Or use a normal button(`type='button'`) instead of a submit button.

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#result').hide();
        $('#submit').click(function(e) {             
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#hideme').hide();
            $('#result').fadeIn(5000);
        });
    });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/3252H/11/)

Comment: @user3104720 Try my demo.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy now it hides my div and shows but submit is not sending the values to PHP. How do i do that ?

Comment: @user3104720 You can ask that as a new question, so that you can get more attention over there. :)

Comment: As I said. to post you need to AJAX

Answer (score -1):

To post you need to AJAX and preventDefault to not submit
Also never call anything in a form submit

```js
$(function() {
  $('#result').hide();
  $('#form1').on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop form submission
    $('#hideme').hide();
    $.post(this.action, { "name": $("input[name='name']").val()},function(data) {
      $('#result').html(data).fadeIn(5000);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">Fade me in and hide div hideme</div>
<div id="hideme">
  <form id="form1" method="POST" action="someaction.php">
    YES <input type="radio" name="name" value="yes" /> NO <input type="radio" name="name" value="no" checked />
    <p />
    <input type="submit" value="HIDE NOW!" />
  </form>
</div>
```